# Access Javascript Object Value with Dynamic Key

Tags: javascript, object, graphql

How do you handle accessing the objects inside a JSON response when the key is dynamic?

In my code sample, I've created a reducer that makes API calls but requires params to work:

```js
import { fetchAPI } from '../lib/api'

export async function resultsReducer(dataType, sortParam, nodeFields) { 
  let allResults = []
  let fetch = await fetchAPI(`
    query {
      ${dataType} (sortBy: ${sortParam}) {
        pageInfo {
          hasNextPage
          startCursor
          endCursor
        }
        edges {
          node {
            ${nodeFields}
          }
          cursor
        }
        totalCount
      }
    }
  `)

  // How I access the dataType key - this doesn't work 
  fetch.dataType.edges.map( (item) => {
    allResults.push(item)
  })
}
```

That function works and it returns a response that gets deposited on `fetch` that looks like this:

```js
{
  allLocationss: {
    pageInfo: {
      hasNextPage: true,
      startCursor: 'YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjA=',
      endCursor: 'YXJyYXljb25uZWN0aW9uOjE5'
    },
    edges: [
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object], [Object],
      [Object], [Object]
    ],
    totalCount: 52
  }
}
```

In my example response, `allLocationss` is the key, but some times it's `allTopics` or `allEvents`, etc. If I use `Object.keys(fetch)[1]` I get a string returned. I also tried `fetch.Object.keys(fetch)[1].edges` but that doesn't work either. Would love some ideas S.O.

Comment: "The best answer I've seen is use Object.keys(fetch)[1] but that doesn't seem to work". What do you mean "doesn't work"? What does that give you and what do you want instead?

Comment: I suggest doing `console.log(fetch)` to see the returned object. This should give you ideas how to proceed. Maybe something as simple as `fetch[dataType]` will do what you want, if the value of `dataType` is a key in the object returned by GraphQL. If not, please explain further what your desired result is here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice - updated with JSON response and some of the experiments I've tried. This is a question about how to access items in an object if you don't have the key ahead of time, not sure it matters too much what the response looks like but I added it anyway.

Comment: In a single go it would be `fetch[Object.keys(fetch)[0]].edges`. But since you already know and provide the `dataType` you could use `fetch[dataType].edges`

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli - interesting, I guess you need the `['string']` syntax to use a dynamic key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access dynamic key in response use `variable[key]` notations

```
// How I access the dataType key?
fetch[dataType].edges.map((item) => {
  allResults.push(item);
});
```

Comment: I didn't realize you can put the key name for an obj in brackets like that, works perfectly now.

Comment: @serraosays Checkout https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects for a quick overview of objects. The examples use bracket notation without really mentioning it, so it might be easy to miss.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bracket notation to access the key with `dataType`'s value:

```
fetch[dataType]
```

Since `map()` already creates an array, you don't need to declare `allResults.push()`. Instead, just use the array returned by `map()`:

```
const allResults = fetch[dataType].edges.map(item => item);
```

In fact, if you don't need a copy of the array, you can just assign directly:

```
const allResults = fetch[dataType].edges;
```